# Stored Procedure result into temp table in Azure Data Warehouse

Tags: sql-server, azure, stored-procedures, azure-synapse

In `Azure Data Warehouse`, i have a `Stored Procedure` which will return the result of `SELECT` command.

How to push the `Stored Procedure` result into temp table?

I tried the below query and it is returning an error message.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp
(name varchar(255), created_date datetime)
GO
INSERT INTO #temp
EXEC sp_testproc
```

Output message:

```
Msg 103010, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Parse error at line: 2, column: 1: Incorrect syntax near 'EXEC'.
```

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? I'm specifically interested about pushing system sp results.

Comment: No, I have not. Also, I am not working in Azure DW nowadays.

Answer (score 6):

Azure SQL Data Warehouse does not support `INSERT ... EXEC` as per [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-stored-procedures#insertexecute).  However, temp tables also have a different scope which means they can be viewed *outside* stored procedures that create them.  Simply create your temp table inside the stored proc, and it can be viewed once the stored proc has executed, eg:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.usp_getTableNames') IS NOT NULL DROP PROC dbo.usp_getTableNames;
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.usp_getTableNames
AS

    -- Drop table if already exists
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tables') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tables;

    -- Create temp table for viewing outside stored procedure
    CREATE TABLE #tables
    (
        [object_id]     INT NOT NULL,
        name            SYSNAME NOT NULL
    )
    WITH
    (
        DISTRIBUTION = HASH([object_id]),
        HEAP
    );


    INSERT INTO #tables
    SELECT object_id, name
    FROM sys.tables;

GO

-- Run the proc
EXEC dbo.usp_getTableNames;
GO


-- The table table is still available for reading outside the scope of the stored procedure
SELECT *
FROM #tables;

DROP TABLE #tables;
GO
```

A similar example is available in the 'Modularizing code' section of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-tables-temporary#modularizing-code) article.  It's just a slightly different order of doing things.

Comment: is there anyway to store the results of a system Sproc say sp_spaceused?